# Dice game between 2 players up to a score of 50

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am creating a game where two players are rolling dice against each other.

Two people (player A, player B) play a dice game. they roll a dice each round and the higher number wins the game and the winner earn 5 points.If two people roll the same value of dice, they both earn 3 points. The game ends if one player reaches 50 points or higher. If both players reach 50 at the same round, that becomes deuce and one more round of game to go until higher value player wins the game (if the 11th round still tie, play next round. Here is my code so far, but I am not getting any of the scores to go to 50 to end the game.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int playerA[] = new int[10];
    int playerB[] = new int[10];
    int playerAScore = 0;
    int playerBScore = 0;
    int round = 1;
    
    for (int i =0; i < playerA.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Roll the die for round " + round++);
        playerA[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        playerB[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    
        System.out.println("player A has " + playerA[i] + " and player B has " + playerB[i]);
    
        if(playerA[i] == playerB[i]) {
            playerAScore = playerAScore + 3;
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 3;
        }
        else if (playerA[i] > playerB[i]) {
            playerAScore = playerAScore + 5;
        }
        else if (playerB[i] > playerB[i]) {
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 5;
        }
        if(playerAScore >= 50 || playerBScore >= 50) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The game is over.");
    
    if(playerAScore >= playerBScore)
        System.out.println("The winner is player A");
    else
        System.out.println("The winner is player B");
    
    System.out.println("How many rounds of game played?");
    System.out.println("Rounds played: " + round);
    
    System.out.println("Total Score per player:");
    System.out.println("Player A score: " + playerAScore);
    System.out.println("Player B score: " + playerBScore);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like a typo or copy/paste error at `} else if (playerB[i] > playerB[i]) {`.

Comment: I think the odds of getting either player's score to 50 in just 10 rounds is very slim.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, replace `for loop` with a `while loop` on condition `(playerAScore < 50 && playerBScore < 50) && playerAScore != playerBScore`.

Comment: When you get this working, I suggest you post the code on [codereview.se]. I think you could learn a lot that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `for` loop you should use `while`. In your case one of the players have to win every time to score 50 points. Try this: `while (playerAScore < 50 && playerBScore < 50)` and increment index `i` inside the loop.

Comment: If only this change is made, `i` will go beyond the array bounds and crash the program.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the comparison between scores you have a typo.

```
playerB[i] > playerB[i]
```

which is always false, so one player doesn't get his points at all.

```
        else if (playerB[i] > playerB[i]) {
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 5;
        }
```

fragment. Which obviously should be:

```
        else if (playerB[i] > playerA[i]) {
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 5;
        }
```

2. Second mistake is probably that you are playing only `playerA.length` times. Which in this case is 10, so player gets 50 only in case he wins all of the games (which is very very low probability).
3. Number of rounds displayed at the end is wrong. The number of played rounds is `10` while it is incremented once more and states the number of rounds is `11`

Comment: I think simply `else` works here as well. And a string of ties also would get both players over 50, but that's also very low probability.

Comment: You're right about playerB > playerA but it's redundent since if a != b and a < b then b must be > a.

Edit; Fred beat me to it by 5 seconds :p

Comment: If he wants to explicitly state it, there's no point in not allowing him. Maybe he finds it more readable? Anyways - that's the root of an error for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have pointed out the flaw with `PlayerB > PlayerB` however this answer is pointed towards how to fix the issue of only player 10 rounds. Instead of limiting to 10, allow a function to execute recursively until 50 score it met.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();

        game.round(50);

        System.out.println("The game is over.");

        if(game.playerAScore >= game.playerBScore)
            System.out.println("The winner is player A");
        else
            System.out.println("The winner is player B");

        System.out.println("How many rounds of game played?");
        System.out.println("Rounds played: " + game.round);

        System.out.println("Total Score per player:");
        System.out.println("Player A score: " + game.playerAScore);
        System.out.println("Player B score: " + game.playerBScore);
    }
```

```java
    static class Game {

        private int playerAScore = 0;

        private int playerBScore = 0;

        private int round;

        void round(int maximumScore) {
            System.out.println("Roll the die for round " + round);

            int playerARoll = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

            int playerBRoll = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

            System.out.println("player A has " + playerARoll + " and player B has " + playerBRoll);

            if (playerARoll == playerBRoll) {
                playerAScore += 3;
                playerBScore += 3;
            } else if (playerARoll > playerBRoll) {
                playerAScore += 5;
            } else {
                playerBScore += 5;
            }
            if(playerAScore >= maximumScore || playerBScore >= maximumScore) {
                return;
            }
            round++;
            round(maximumScore);
        }
    }
```

Output

```
Roll the die for round 0
player A has 2 and player B has 2
Roll the die for round 1
player A has 2 and player B has 2
Roll the die for round 2
player A has 6 and player B has 6
Roll the die for round 3
player A has 6 and player B has 6
Roll the die for round 4
player A has 6 and player B has 3
Roll the die for round 5
player A has 5 and player B has 2
Roll the die for round 6
player A has 2 and player B has 2
Roll the die for round 7
player A has 3 and player B has 1
Roll the die for round 8
player A has 2 and player B has 4
Roll the die for round 9
player A has 6 and player B has 6
Roll the die for round 10
player A has 1 and player B has 4
Roll the die for round 11
player A has 2 and player B has 3
Roll the die for round 12
player A has 2 and player B has 5
Roll the die for round 13
player A has 6 and player B has 4
Roll the die for round 14
player A has 1 and player B has 2
Roll the die for round 15
player A has 1 and player B has 5
Roll the die for round 16
player A has 3 and player B has 4
The game is over.
The winner is player B
How many rounds of game played?
Rounds played: 16
Total Score per player:
Player A score: 38
Player B score: 53
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just made a typo in the line:

```
else if (playerB[i] > playerA[i]) playerBScore = playerBScore + 5;
}
```

Here is the amended code:

```
public class diceGame{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int playerA[] = new int[10];
    int playerB[] = new int[10];
    int playerAScore = 0;
    int playerBScore = 0;
    int round = 1;
    
    for (int i =0; i < playerA.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Roll the die for round " + round++);
        playerA[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        playerB[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    
        System.out.println("player A has " + playerA[i] + " and player B has " + playerB[i]);
    
        if(playerA[i] == playerB[i]) {
            playerAScore = playerAScore + 3;
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 3;
        }
        else if (playerA[i] > playerB[i]) {
            playerAScore = playerAScore + 5;
        }
        else if (playerB[i] > playerA[i]) {
            playerBScore = playerBScore + 5;
        }
        if(playerAScore >= 50 || playerBScore >= 50) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The game is over.");
    
    if(playerAScore >= playerBScore)
        System.out.println("The winner is player A");
    else
        System.out.println("The winner is player B");
    
    System.out.println("How many rounds of game played?");
    System.out.println("Rounds played: " + round);
    
    System.out.println("Total Score per player:");
    System.out.println("Player A score: " + playerAScore);
    System.out.println("Player B score: " + playerBScore);
    
}
}
```